# Preferences of compiler flags

Tags: linux, gcc

If I pass LDFLAGS, extra ld flags and library exists in /lib, /usr/lib,
from which location libraries will be picked, from LDFLAGS or extra ld flags or /lib and /usr/lib ?

Also if I pass `LDFLAGS='-L/path1 -L/path2 -L/path3'`
which path will be checked first, path3 or path1 ?

Comment: specified flags obviously have priority.. now, the question is why would you mix these?

Comment: I have an utility(which i cant change for some reason) to install multiple packages,it passes some LDFLAGS to configure (using a variable which is exported to makefile of all packages),i have a development pc so these libraries may be present in my filesystem,i cant add LDFLAGS variable as it will be passed to all packages,for only few packages i need special flags along with LDFLAGS.

Comment: so i want to control with which libraries my package gets compiled :) so i wanted to know preference of these flags,

Comment: i think extra flags are appended behind LDFLAGS,but not sure whether libs will be picked from {/lib or /usr/lib } or from the one passed in LDFLAGS

Comment: 1) flags have preference. 2) for the order of extra flags, check your Makefile. 3) the same library shouldn't be in both /lib and /usr/lib.